# Why is curl treating my username like a URL?

Tags: curl

I'm trying to figure out what headers are being sent by a remote server, using cURL to view the request. The remote server uses http basic authentication.

I make the request:

```
curl --basic -D -u 'username' https://my.server.location
```

And it outputs:

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: username
```

Before then outputting the response from the server as if I tried to access without providing credentials.

Why is curl ignoring the commandline -u argument and attempting to make a request to my username, as if it was a URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are supposed to pass a file to dump the headers used the `-D` option.

Use

```
curl --basic -D myfile -u 'username' https://my.server.location
```

If you want to dump them to stdout, use

```
curl --basic -D - -u 'username' https://my.server.location
```

Or remove the `-D` option:

```
curl --basic -u 'username' https://my.server.location
```

Comment: Thanks. That stops it trying to load my username as a URL (which is what I asked) but it still doesn't send the login credentials.

Comment: The -D options is the problem. Remove it. I'm checking out why.

Comment: @Hippyjim Figured out why. The space wasn't the problem actually.

Comment: Yup - that got it. Thanks @blue112